# Rivets formatter when each argument is another formatter

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I want to check if **table.value** is equal to **'Stack'** or **'Overflow'**.

I would like to do something like this:

```
rv-if="table.value | eq 'Stack' | or (table.value | eq 'Overflow')"

rivets.formatters.eq = function (value, args)  { 
         return value === args;
};

rivets.formatters.or = function (value, args)  { 
         return value || args;
};
```

I would like to use those 2 formatters to achieve this.

I know I can have a specific formatter like this to achieve my functionality.

```
rivets.formatters.checkIfValueEqualsEitherArg = function (value, arg1, arg2)  { 
             return (value === arg1) || (value===arg2);
};
```

But, I would rather use the above two generic formatters (eq and or).

What is the best way to achieve this

**Update**

Since, I was not able to get any help on this here, or elsewhere, this is what I have done to achieve my functionality. I am still waiting on right response.

```
rv-if="table.value | checkIfValueEqualsEitherArg 'Stack' 'Overflow'"
```

Comment: `['Stack', 'Overflow'].indexOf(table.value) >= 0`

Comment: @hindmost Please look at my edited question. I am sorry I was not specific enough.